# Pass a list of derived types in order to store them as a member

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, polymorphism, c++14

I have a class `widget`.
I have an abstract class `base` with derivates `derived_a`, `derived_b`, etc.

I want `widget` to hold an arbitrary amount of objects that are derivated from `base` in order to later use them polymorphically.

My first attempt looks like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class widget {
public:
    explicit widget(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>>&& params) :
    members {std::move (params)}
    {            
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> members;
};
```

And would be called like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> v;
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_a>()));
widget w (std::move(v));
```

However, this solution seams unnessesarry verbose and not user friendly at all, especially when providing multiple types:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> v;
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_a>()));
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_b>()));
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_c>()));
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_a>()));
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_b>()));
v.push_back(std::move(std::make_unique<derived_c>()));
widget w {std::move(v)};
```

Instead, I would prefer usage along the lines of

```
widget w {derived_a(), 
          derived_b(), 
          derived_c(), 
          derived_a(), 
          derived_b(), 
          derived_c()};
```

so that `widget` is provided with a list of rvalues that it then can turn into `std::vector<unique_ptr<base>>`.
I have the impression that this can be achieved through templating the ctor, but, despite intensive googling, I have no clue on how to achieve my goal exactly.

Please note that the class template solution that would look tike this:

```
widget<derived_a, 
       derived_b, 
       derived_c, 
       derived_a, 
       derived_b, 
       derived_c> w;
```

Is undesirable, as I need to provide some deriveds with parameters.

Comment: Sorry - I did not think about OOP problems in a while... But could you not achieve some easier coding by using a factory class? ``class wf { static std::unique_ptr<derived_a> make_a(/*maybe some args*/) { ... }; ... };`` and then ``widget w; w.visuals( { wf::make_a(); ... } )``?

Comment: just for a bit "less" verbose. AFAIK you don't need the `move` in the `push_back`

Comment: Well trying my factory idea kind of flopped. It seems ``std::unique<>`` has problems handling abstract base classes. Who would have guessed they internally try to make copies? :)

Comment: @Hayt yeah, that `std::move` is achieving absolutely nothing while bloating the written code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `initializer_list`, but you can use variadic template:

```
class widget {
public:
    template <typename ... Ts>
    explicit widget(Ts&&... params) 
    {
        int dummy[] =
            {0, (members.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Ts>(std::forward<Ts>(params))), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid unused variable warning
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> members;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2b1fba18494a463)

or in C++17, with folding expression:

```
    template <typename ... Ts>
    explicit widget(Ts&&... params) 
    {
        (members.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Ts>(std::forward<Ts>(params))), ...);
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `std::move` I would rather use `std::forward`.

Comment: @themagicalyang doing this gave me `'std::forward': no matching overloaded function found` in MSVC while the version with `std::move` works perfectly

Comment: @JanNilsFerner It does work on clang 3.8 and gcc 6.1 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31d9cc1434505b55

Comment: Very creative combination of the array with the pack expansion. Does this idiom have a name?

Comment: @JanNilsFerner It's the comma operator. The `...` expand to the comma operators usage.

Comment: @themagicalyang Very interesting, thank you. I was in fact wondering why the error occured. Seems like another microsoft specific bug.

Comment: @JanNilsFerner : "*Seems like another microsoft specific bug.*" VC++ compiles this code fine either way. I'd wager you changed it from `std::move(` to `std::forward(` rather than the correct `std::forward<Ts>(`.

Comment: @ildjarn Ha, you're right! TIL. Thank you very much for correcting me